# UIButton image with custom icon size

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uikit, interface-builder

If I have a UIButton in a xib file. Is possible to set per icon button with custom icon size in the xib file?

es. I have a 40x40 image mia_immagine.png
but I would like to set this as an icon of the button but with size (image) 20x20

Comment: What you have tried? What problem you face?

Comment: I set my image (via interface biulder)
I have a button 40x40
and a image 40x40
I have set this image to my button
I see the button with the large 40x40 icon
I would like to set this icon 20x20 and leave the frame of the button to 40x40.

Comment: u can use a shortcut , keep UIImageView of 20x20 size over UIButton of size 40x40 and set image to UIImageView

Answer (score 0):

Use this to resize the image:

```
+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );  
   [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];  
   UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();  
   return newImage;    
}
```

And to use in a button:

> > [btn setBackgroundImage:[YourClass imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_imag.png"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake:(20,20)];

And set the content mode Centered